# Nth child targeting the wrong element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using nth child to remove the margin of certain elements on the right:

```
.post-list-item:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

But somehow it's seems to be targetting the wrong elements:
http://poachedmag.com/column/entertainment/music/

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have another div tag inside the parent div. So the right-most elements aren't #3, #6, and #9, but #4, #7, and #10. So either remove this extra div tag or change your CSS to:

```
.post-list-item:nth-child(3n+4) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: this is also correct. I used a <template> tag instead of a div, and I'm expecting it shouldn't be counted in nth-child but I was wrong